# How can I find first 10 countries that has highest number of women who won Nobel award

Tags: database, sparql, dbpedia

I'm new to querying DBPedia. How can I find first 10 countries that has highest number of women who won Nobel award from http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: This will be quite a complex query. Please show your attempts

Comment: Have you browsed any of the questions tagged with [tag:dbpedia] and [tag:sparql] here on Stack Overflow?  There are lots of examples.  On Stack Overflow, it's better to show what you've attempted, and to describe precisely what you're looking for, so that you can get detailed answers. As written, this question is too broad and doesn't *show* any research effort or attempts (regardless of what you might have already done).

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?origin (COUNT(?origin) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?w dbo:birthPlace ?origin .
  ?w dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Women_Nobel_laureates> .
}
GROUP BY ?origin
ORDER BY DESC (?count)
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This isn't a legal SPARQL query.  You can check with [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query), which reports, "Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?origin".  To make this legal, you'd need at add `group by ?origin`.

Comment: Most likely a typo - just add 'GROUP BY ?origin' to the end of the query and it works fine.

Comment: I was testing directly through the http://dbpedia.org/sparql endpoint - didn't throw any issues.

Comment: The GROUP BY clause is necessary to create the aggregate (COUNT).  Not sure why you did not receive the error about the non-group variable.